# Getting "App2SD is not supported" error when trying to move an app to my SD card

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, app2sd, link2sd

I’m using an Android LG Tribute phone, which I have rooted.  I want to move some apps to my SD Card and so I installed the “LInk2SD” app (because there was no “Move to SD Card” for any of my applications in the Settings -> App section of my phone).  When I go into Link2SD, select an application, and click the “Move to SD Card” button, I get the error

```
App2SD is not supported by your device. Because your device has a primary external storage which is emulated from the internal storage. You can link the app in order to move its files to your SD card.
```

I have read in other posts that the solution is to link instead of move, however in each application, the “LINK TO SD CARD” button is greyed out.  I don’t care particularly about Link2SD but I am interested in how I can start moving some stuff to my SD Card.  Any advice about fixing the above error message is appreciated, - Dave